# How to access mysql record outside function in exprees.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am doing following code.

```
var data=[];
sequelize.query("SELECT `name`,`mobile` FROM `emp_table` LIMIT 0,50",function(result){
     data['main']=result;
});
console.log(data['main']); // returns 'undefined'
```

I have used callback hell method. But I think this is not a right way.
Please help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

since nodeJS in asynchronous  `console.log(data['main']);` would be executed first, as the query is been processed(fetching data from db is async call).

you can try below code to get expected output.

```
var data=[];
sequelize.query("SELECT `name`,`mobile` FROM `emp_table` LIMIT 
0,50",function(result){
data['main']=result;
console.log(data['main']);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean with the callback hell method. But you're using a callback (the function supplied as a parameter) in the `query()` call. That function is only being called whenever `query()`'s body calls it. Making it behave asynchronous.

Problem now is, is the `console.log` is outside this 'async-loop' and ran sequentially. So `data['main']` is actually undefined by the time `console.log` is called.

To fix it do this:

```
var data=[];
sequelize.query("SELECT `name`,`mobile` FROM `emp_table` LIMIT 0,50",function(result){
     data['main']=result;
     console.log(data['main']);
});
```

Move `console.log` into the callback.

Comment: I know the data is getting inside the callback. But I want data outside..

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `promise` when fetching data from db. You can print your data in `then` part of your code. Example: 
Service that calls fetch data from db and returns a promise.

```
exports.getAllUsers = function() {
    // this is the place where you will execute your query.
    return models.user.findAll();
};
```

In the controller, the data is printed as.

```
userService.getAllUsers().then(function (result) {
        if (result != null) {
            res.status(200).json({
                status: "success",
                data: result
            });
        } else {
            res.status(404).json({
                status: "fail",
                data: "No data found"
            });
        }
    }
```